# Красивая регулярка для ссылок

Tags: php

Есть 3 ссылки, одной строкой, назовём условно это "массив" -

```
http://www.russianfood.com/recipes/recipe.php?rid=120590|http://www.gastronom.ru/recipe/14679/makarony-po-flotski|http://webspoon.ru/receipt/makarony-po-flotski
```

разделённые вот таким символом - `|` Уважаемые гуру, подскажите регулярочку, что бы из этого "массива" получились реальные ссылки, только вот так:

```
www.russianfood.com
www.gastronom.ru
webspoon.ru
```

но, только так что бы он выводил столько конечных ссылок, сколько их в "массиве".

Извините, пока сам только познаю регулярные выражения, научился только этому:

```
echo str_replace('|', '<br>', $composition);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста пример по моему сабжу, буду крайне признателен. Спасибо!

Comment: 1) [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) - разбиваем на массив ссылок, 2) [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) - достаем имя хоста для каждого элемента массива

Comment: @BOPOH Спасибо сейчас попробую! Скажите, а для Вашего рецепта ещё нужно будет в цикле элементы выводить?

Comment: что значит "выводить"? на страницу? да, сначала получаете нужные данные, потом их выводите, не смешивайте логику с отображением

Comment: @BOPOH Спасибо! Всё получилось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pi_mass = explode('|', (ссыль1|ссыль2|ссыль3));
$pi_count = count($pi_mass);
for($j=0;$j<$pi_count;$j++){
?><a href="<? echo $pi_mass[$j]; ?>"><? echo parse_url($pi_mass[$j], PHP_URL_HOST); ?></a></br><?}
```

По-моему тут скобки одной не хватает?

P.S. Не могу отредактировать сообщение.

P.S. [2] Дополнил ответ исправив опечатку, добавил скобку.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/70692)

Comment: insolor, готово.

Comment: Всё верно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @BOPOH за наводку, маны - великая сила!!!

```
$pi_mass = explode('|', (ссыль1|ссыль2|ссыль3);
$pi_count = count($pi_mass);
for($j=0;$j<$pi_count;$j++){
?><a href="<? echo $pi_mass[$j]; ?>"><? echo parse_url($pi_mass[$j], PHP_URL_HOST); ?></a></br><?}
```

Comment: используй `foreach($pi_mass as $_mass)` так удобнее в `$_mass` будет значение

Comment: @Naumov Да, спасибо! Это действительно проще.